# Hot to run a class method in spring as a thread when the app loads?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

i need to run a class from quartz-schedualer, and i need it to be running always and parallel form the main app. The class will always be cheking for new files in a folder to process. I though to include it as a listener in the web.xml, how ever this way the constructor does not run, only the calss is loaded. Any sugestions ?

Here what i added in the web.xml:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.bamboo.common.util.QuartzSchedualer</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is how i declared the class:

```
public class QuartzSchedualer {

     public void QuartzSchedualer (){
                try{

                    // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory

                    Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();


                    // and start it off

                    scheduler.start();


                    scheduler.shutdown();

                }  catch (SchedulerException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include it in web.xml, just load your appcontext in your web.xml as you already do probably, and deal with the scheduling within spring:

The job referring to your business object which has the method to be invoked:

```
<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="exampleBusinessObject" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="doIt" />
  <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
```

The trigger that takes care of firing the method:

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="exampleJob" />
  <!-- run every morning at 6 AM -->
  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ?" />
</bean>
```

The schedulerFactoryBean for wiring the trigger:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  <property name="triggers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

See further in [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html) for 2.5, [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) for 3.0.