# Spring Quartz Scheduling

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

In my application there is a requirement to be able to create Scheduled Job(s) for My sql database autobackup

Can I use Spring Quartz Scheduling to create this Jobs?

Any help would be useful.

Amulraj.P

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, though it seems a bit overkill. Backuping an MSSQL db can be done using commandline tools, which you can easily schedule to run using cron if you are using Unix or Scheduled Tasks on Windows.

```
%PATH_TO_SQL_SERVER%\Tools\Binn\osql.exe
-E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE mydb TO DISK='%PATH_TO_BKP%\db.bak' WITH FORMAT"
```

For you question the answer is something like this: (shameless self-copy from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038880/hot-to-run-a-class-method-in-spring-as-a-thread-when-the-app-loads/6042252#6042252))

The job referring to your business object which has the method which takes care of the backup:

```
<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="exampleBusinessObject" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="backupDB" />
  <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
```

The trigger that takes care of firing the method:

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  <property name="jobDetail" ref="exampleJob" />
  <!-- run every morning at 6 AM, use regular cron expressions-->
  <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 6 * * ?" />
</bean>
```

The schedulerFactoryBean for wiring the trigger:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  <property name="triggers">
    <list>
      <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

See further in [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html) for 2.5, [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) for 3.0.